# Test of confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference

In one of my assignments I have to "test" if the confidence intervals (CIs) for a set of parameters in a mixed effect model is accurate. I'm asked to simulate from fitted parameters and after that to refit them using the same model many times. Lastly, I need to take 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles of them and compare with the original CIs. My question is, how does this procedure in any way measure how accurate my original confidence intervals were?

Comment: Isn't it just an homework exercise to show "how does CI's work"..?